# Projeto C no Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

Estou aprendendo C na faculdade e terei que programar em C.

Testei com o Visual Studio 2013 e o 2019 Community edition consigo criar projetos em C++, mas não encontrei nada parecido com um "Visual C".

Existe alguma forma ou extensão que permita a criação de projetos em C puro?

Comment: Eu nunca tentei compilar C no VS 2013, mas imagino que seja o mesmo de versões anteriores. Você nunca tentou em outras versões? Verei se consigo escrever uma resposta mas já adianto que, salvo existir algo que eu não sei, precisa criar um projeto C++ mesmo e compilar os arquivos `.c` e `.h` para indicar que é C e não C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta criar um projeto Win32 vazio e acrescentar um fonte com extensão "C". Você também pode forçar o compilador para que só aceite código ANSI, conforme mostrado abaixo :

Configuration Properties->Advanced->Compile As : Compile as C Code(/TC)

Answer (score 1):

Sim, mas você terá que usar um projeto de C++ pra conseguir escrever em C:

[image: C++ Project]

[Este site](http://winquire.org/2013/02/03/creating-a-c-project-in-visual-studio/) dá mais alguns detalhes sobre como usar uma estrutura pura de C.